# How to get the absoulte url path of uploaded file using flask

Tags: python, flask

I have created a simple flask web app. It has a upload feature and a get url feature.
The upload features uploads the file as

```
UPLOAD_FOLDER = "./myuploads/"
app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"] = UPLOAD_FOLDER
```

And I am saving the file as follows:

```
file.save (app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"], file.filename)
```

In the get URL feature I want that the server returns the path of the file stored. On localhost PC I used

```
os.path.join(app.instance_path + app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER "], " somefilename.ext ")
```

It returns the absolute path of the file stored in local host but as soon as I upload it on heroku it returns **/app/instance/myuploads/somefile.ext**
But this URL is not opening, how to get the absolute path. I have also tried with **app.root_path**, the result is same

I want the path look like **https://myhero.herokuapp.com/somedirs/somefile.ext**

Comment: fwiw, there's a typo in the code file.save() line.  I'm guessing it should be ```app.config["UPLOAD_FOLDER"]```

Comment: Thanks Ewong. Do you know the solution?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it will be helpful for anyone else.
But I needed to display images and give the option to upload them to dropbox which requires a url.

I did this with:

```
img = BytesIO()
b = Image.open("/tmp/image.png")
b.save(img, format="PNG")
img.seek(0)
plot_url = base64.b64encode(img.getvalue()).decode()
im_source = "data:image/png;base64,{}".format(plot_url)
filename = "image.png"

render_template("page.html", image=im_source, filename=filename)
```

Then make a button to send to drop box and send the file like so:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.dropbox.com/static/api/2/dropins.js" id="dropboxjs" data-app-key="your_key"></script>

<a href="{{image}}" data-filename="{{filename}}" class="dropbox-saver"></a>
```